# How can I make a Random Word Generator in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, random

All right, so basically all I want is for a bunch of words that I input into a string(would I use one?) and then a random one would be outputted in a TextBox. So,
I'd have a list of words (let's say 100 words) and then I'd make it randomly put out 1 of those 100 words in a TextBox.
Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

see[select a random value from an array](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB75_How-to-select-a-random-value-from-an-array.html). here's one of their code samples:

```
// Initialize the string array
string[] strStrings = { "Random string", "Another random value from the array", "Randomly selected index" };
// Choose a random slogan
Random RandString = new Random();
// Display the random slogan
txtRandom.Text = strStrings[RandString.Next(0, strStrings.Length)];
```

After you have a random string from your list, you just set it as the value of the text-box. :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd want to use a string but rather a generic list of strings.  Then use the random method to return a number between 0 and 99 inclusive, and then use the random number to access the list index.

Comment: If this is the extend of the requirements, using a generic List<string> doesn't add anything that string[] isn't already giving you.

Comment: True, but reading the OP's questions I thought he meant concatenating the list into a single string variable.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it, in addition to CrazyJugglerDrummer's solution, is to use the modulus function in conjunction with the current Ticks.

```
string[] strings = { "String1", "String2", "String3" };
int position = DateTime.Now.Ticks % strings.Length;
string randomString = strings[position];
```

Comment: If there's a built in class designed for exactly your purpose, you should use that instead of designing the functionality on your own. The people who produced the class probably put a lot more than five minutes of thought into it, and you should use their proven work.

In this case you're using Ticks when what you really want is just a random value.